# Database instance inside GUI - MongoDB

Tags: java, swing, mongodb

I have this GUI to connect to my MongoDB database:

[image]

When you insert a Database name, for example `test`, and press `OK` button I want to connect my application to MongoDB database.
So I implemented it in this way the `actionPerformed` method on `OK` button:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Database db = new Database(this.textField.getText());
    this.setVisible(false);
    window2 = new Frame2();
    window2.setVisible(true);
    window2.textArea1.append("Connect to database \""+ db.getDb() + "\" successfully!\n\n");
    window2.textArea1.append("Choose a collection:");
}
```

`Frame2` is a new `JFrame` that becomes visible when you press `OK` and shows a message in a `JTextArea` called `textArea1`.
This is the constructor of Database class:

```
public Database(String dbName) {        
    super();
    try {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
        this.db = client.getDB(dbName);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Is it correct to create a Database instance inside actionPerformed method?

Comment: I'd separate my application into a model, a view, and one or more controllers.  Reading from and writing to a database would be part of the GUI model.